# iTwin Exporter for Datasmith stops working and shuts down by itself after clicking export option

Tags: bentley-itwin

I am trying to export my iModel to use it in Unreal Engine. However, iTwin Exporter for Datasmith stops working and shuts down by itself after clicking export option.

Comment: Looks like this was reposted to iTwin.js's suggested question forum, https://github.com/iTwin/itwinjs-core/discussions/5370